# What type of answer should I accept?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Which type of answer should I accept?

1. The first answer that helped and satisfied my problem, but maybe required a bit of exploration
2. The first answer that provided all the necessary information
3. The answer which was very specific, came a bit later, and would be the most helpful for someone who comes to the question later
4. the answer that helped *me* the most but may not help someone else with the same problem

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93800/deciding-what-answer-to-accept-the-correct-one-liner-or-the-later-elaborate-one

Comment: Imo, you should accept that answer that helps you the most, gives the answer of your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option 4: The answer that helped you the most.

If there is another answer that you know is the *best* answer (i.e. the one that is most helpful *in general*), you can accept that one instead.

Comment: Often "helped *me* the most" and "most helpful in general" are the same thing. Depends what you consider helpful.

 - Helped me get a quick-n-dirty solution so I could get back to work VS 
 - Helped me *understand* my problem and become a better coder

Comment: In fact, if there's a significant disconnect between "helped you the most" and "most helpful in general" then that may be cause to identify localized material in the problem/question and clean it up a bit.

Comment: Probably should be noted that "most helpful in general" is signified by the vote totals, not the acceptance mark. Of course, they can intersect, though.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

- accept the one that helped *you* the most - point 4
- upvote good answers (useful, clear, relevant, ...) - point 3, probably 4, maybe 2

being the first answer should only (eventually) be considered for equivalent answers - the *same* answer an hour later is no real *addition*.