# Which answer should I accept, the quickest or the most complete?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)
>   [Deciding what answer to accept: the correct one-liner or the later elaborate one with code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93800/deciding-what-answer-to-accept-the-correct-one-liner-or-the-later-elaborate-one)

I just got two answers on my question.

This happened (chronologically):
- Person A answers the question correctly
- Person B answers the question but gives a slightly better answer
- Person A edits his answer including Person's B answer

Probably person A read person B's answer and decided to edit his one.
So person A has a more complete answer (including both his and the persons B's answer) but person B gave the best answer.

Which one should I accept? The most complete answer or should I give the credits to the one giving the best answer first?

Comment: If someone downvotes it, please add a comment why please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept the answer that is *most helpful to you.*  Let the community's voting sort the rest out.

Comment: Even after somebody copies somebody else's answer to get the reputation himself?

Comment: Well, that's not really helpful now, is it?  You get to decide what to do with the checkmark.  Use your own best judgement.

Comment: I did and I accepted the one that gave the solution I could use ... and I let also count that the other probably copied the answer and the one who gave only the good answer did not have much reputation so he probably is more happy with the reputation gain :-)

Comment: Btw, my question is not a duplicate of the ones mentioned above as duplicates but maybe I should have rephrased the question. So I probably will ask it again sooner or later.