# Two answers answer my question, but in a different way. How should I choose which one to accept?

Tags: discussion

I recently had a question that had two good answers, both of them were valid solutions to my problem. How do I decide which one to accept?

Comment: also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93800/deciding-what-answer-to-accept-the-correct-one-liner-or-the-later-elaborate-one